# Arquillian with cucumber Build Failure

Tags: java, cucumber, bdd, jboss-arquillian, cucumber-jvm

I'm trying to build a maven project with Arquillian Framework and Cucumber. I'm receiving this message:

[PrintSc of Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xc5Ef.png)

What can I do to fix that?

Comment: you can try deleting everything in `.....info\cukes\cucumber-java\1.2.5\` folder and try a rebuild

Comment: @redflar3 Thanks man, you solved my problem :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like maven is having trouble getting the depended jar. May be the dependency download got interrupted or didn't complete successfully. You can try deleting the `.....info\cukes\cucumber-java\1.2.5` folder and try to rebuild the project. Maven will retry downloading the dependencies and probably will succeed. [answer added for record]